# Drawing integers until we get 0

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Denote by $R(n)$ a random draw of integers between 0 and $n-1$ (inclusive). We
repeatedly apply $R(n)$, starting at $10^{100}$. What’s the expected number of repeated applications until I get zero?

This looks like a optional stopping however the process is not really a martingale. Is there a result for Markov processes that would make the computations easier in this case?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you saying $n=10^{100}$?  Does $n$ change throughout the process?

Comment: @lulu, yes, we consider consecutive iterations of $R$ starting at $10^{100}$.

Comment: You say repeated iteration, do you mean it is recursive (so the range of possible values shrinks somewhat each time)?

Comment: $R$ is undefined.  You should edit your question to make it clear that each iteration uses the last guess as $n$.

Comment: @lulu, what is wrong with $R(n)$? you pick a number from [0, n-1] with probability 1/n.

Comment: As a suggestion:  there is an obvious recursion.  If $k$ is the starting point (so $k=10^{100}$ in your example) and $E_k$ is the answer starting with $k$ then $E_k=1+\frac 1k\times \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}E_i$.  That won't help with $k$ as big yours but it will let you compute $E_k$ for reasonably large $k$...that should at least give you a feeling for the answer and it may be possible to solve the recursion directly.

Comment: I note that the other commenter (@Ian) couldn't understand you either.  $R$ is undefined.  Why make your readers guess what you mean? Please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: what does it mean to apply a number ?

Comment: @mercio $f(x)$ is a value of a function. What does it mean to apply $f(x)$?

Comment: Here the same question gets +2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317879/recursive-random-draw/1318079

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $E(n)$ be the expected number of repeated applications until zero is obtained, starting from $n$.

Then, $E(0) = 0$ and $\displaystyle E(n) = 1 + \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}E(k)$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
nE(n) &=& \displaystyle n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} E(k) \\
(n-1)E(n-1) &=& \displaystyle (n-1) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} E(k) \\
nE(n) - (n-1)E(n-1) &=& 1 + E(n-1) \\
nE(n) - nE(n-1) &=& 1 \\
E(n) &=& \displaystyle \frac1n + E(n-1)
\end{array}$$

which means that $E(n) = \displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac1k = H_n$.

It is well known that $H_n \sim \ln(n)$, so $E(10^{100}) \approx 100 \ln 10 \approx 230.3$.

Comment: I wonder if there is some convexity-type argument to directly justify why $E(n)<\log_2(n)$ (which is more or less what you would anticipate based on pure averaging considerations).

Comment: In this answer, how many integers are drawn at each iteration? Assuming it means n=10^100 at the first iteration, but how does n change in each iteration ("starting at" seems to suggest that it changes)? I seem to not understand the question!